# Symmetrisation of function

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Consider the probability space $\Omega = \{-1, 0, 1\}$ with the $\sigma$-algebra of all possible events and a probability measure $P$. Consider also the smaller $\sigma$-algebra

$$F = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1, -1\}, \Omega\}$$

Prove that, for every function $f : \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$,

$$E(f | F)(\omega) = \frac{f(\omega) + f(-\omega)}{2}$$

Let $B_1, B_2$ be the partition of $F$ with $B_1 = \{0\}$ and $B_2 = \{1, -1\}$. If, for example, $\omega \in B_1$, then;

$$E(f | F)(\omega) = \frac{1}{P(B_1)}(f(-1)P(-1|B_1) + f(1)P(1|B_1) = f(1) + f(-1)$$

which is obviously not the required answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $\mathbb E(f\mid\mathcal F)$ is $\mathcal F$ measurable, hence it has the form $a\chi_{\{0\}}+b\chi_{\{-1,1\}}$. 
Integrating this function over $\{0\}$ and $\{-1,1\}$, we get the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! $\mathbb E(f\mid\mathcal F)$ indeed has to be of the form $a\chi_{\{0\}}+b\chi_{\{-1,1\}}$. I just had one more small question. Suppose we integrate $a\chi_{\{0\}}+b\chi_{\{-1,1\}}$ over $\{-1,1\}$. Then we get $a = \begin{cases} \frac{\mathbb{E}(f \cdot \chi_{\{0\}})}{\mathbb{P}({\{0\}})} & \mathbb{P}({\{0\}}) \not= 0 \\  0 & \mathbb{P}({\{0\}}) = 0 \end{cases}$ and $b = \begin{cases} \frac{\mathbb{E}(f \cdot \chi_{\{-1, 1\}})}{\mathbb{P}({\{-1,1\}})} & \mathbb{P}({\{-1,1\}}) \not= 0 \\  0 & \mathbb{P}({\{-1,1\}}) = 0 \end{cases}$, is this correct?